# timer wrapper function for recursive async/await call

Tags: javascript, promise, timeout, cancellation, retry-logic

I have a recursive async function `getResponse(url,attempts = 0)`, which polls external api for the response and resolves or exits after reaching X number of retries or on a server error.
However, it's internal "clock" is based off the number of retries (after allowing for delays to avoid rate limits), but I also want to have a flexibility in setting a time based timer, which would resolve the function and end the recursion. Ideally, I want to be able to wrap time based timer around my recursive async function, like so `timed(getResponse(url),3400)`

I have only managed to have both the time based and "retries" based timer working together, by packaging both timers in one async function with local variable `expired` serving as an exit flag and setting Promise.race conditions on both functions.

```
async function timedgetResponse (expiry = 3500,url) {
  let expired = false;
  async function timeout(expiry){
    await new Promise(_=> setTimeout(_,expiry));
    expired = true;
    return false;
  };

async function getResponse(url,attempts = 0){
  try {
    if(expired){ return false; };
    const limit = 10;
    if(attempts >= limit){ok: false, e:"MAX_ATTEMPTS"};
    const rawRes = await fetch(url,
      {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include', 
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
      });
    if (!rawRes.ok) {  throw (Error('SERVER_ERROR')); }; 
    const res = await rawRes.json(); 
    if(!res || res.status === 0){ throw (Error(res.request)); };
    return {ok: true, res: res.request};
  } catch(e){
  const err = e.message; 
  if(err === "RESPONSE_NOT_READY"){
    await new Promise(_ => setTimeout(_, 333));
    attempts +=1;   
    return getResponse(url,attempts);
  } else 
  if(err === "SERVER_ERROR_ON_RESOLVER"){
    await new Promise(_ => setTimeout(_, 10000));
    attempts +=1;       
    return getResponse(url,attempts);
  } else {
    return {ok: false, e:"MISC_ERROR"};
  };

};    
};

  const awaited = await Promise.race([
    getResponse(url),
    timeout(expiry)
  ]);

return awaited;
};
```

I sense that it is not a correct way to do it and would appreciate any help towards `timed(getResponse(url),3400)` solution.

Comment: Yes, if you want to stop the retries when the timer expires, then you need the functions work together - there's no way around this. You could separate the functionality only by explicitly supporting cancellation in the retry function.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to also cancel? That's wasn't clear the first time a read your question but based on Bergi's response I feel like that is something you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I have a function that might meet your need. I have updated it based on how I have interpreted your needs. The idea is you will poll until something is true ie resolves or you exceed the max attempts. It has a built-in configurable delay.

The idea here is you'd pass in a function that wraps your fetch call which would eventually resolve/reject.

setPolling(pollFunc, freq = 1000, maxAttempts = 3)

pollFunc = function that takes no args and returns a promise that eventually resolves or rejects.

freq = how frequently to run pollFunc in milliseconds

maxAttempts = max attempts before giving up

```js
const setPolling = async (pollFunc, freq = 1000, maxAttempts = 3, _attempts = 1) => {
  const wait = (delay) => new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(resolve, delay))
  try {
    return await pollFunc()
  } catch (e) {
    if (_attempts < maxAttempts) {
      await wait(freq)
      return await setPolling(pollFunc, freq, maxAttempts, ++_attempts)
    }
    throw (e instanceof Error) ? e : new Error((typeof e !== 'undefined') ? e : 'setPolling maxAttempts exceeded!')
  }
}

async function alwaysFail() {
    throw new Error(`alwaysFail, failed because that's what it does!`)
}

function passAfter(x) {
  let i = 0
  return async ()=> {
    if (i > x) return `passAfter succeeded because i(${i}) > x(${x})`
    throw new Error(`i(${i++}) < x(${x})`)
  }
}

setPolling(alwaysFail)
  .catch((e)=>console.error(`alwaysFail, failed!\n${e.message}\n${e.stack}`))

setPolling(passAfter(5), 500, 10)
  .then((res)=>console.log(`passAfter, succeeded!\n${res}`))
  .catch((e)=>console.error(`passAfter, failed!\n${e.message}\n${e.stack}`))
```

Comment: Does this meet the OP's desire for "a time based timer, which would resolve the function and end the recursion"?

Comment: OP's requirement is not clear. Clarification requested but not given yet.

Comment: Fair enough. I have my own interpretation and will post an answer if I find time.

Answer (score 1):

On the basis that you want to stop retrying when a timer expires, then you can employ a `token` to convey a stop signal to the recursive process.

Something like this should do it:

```
const poll = async (work, options, token) => {
    const settings = Object.assign({ 'delay':0, 'attempts':1, 'maxAttempts':3 }, options);

    // Utility function which returns a Promise-wrapped setTimeout
    const delay = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

    // Two mechanisms for stopping the recursion.
    // Performing the tests here ensures they are applied before the first work() call.
    // 1. token-borne stop signal 
    if(token.stop) {
        throw new Error('poll(): stopped');
    }
    // 2. max attempts reached
    if (settings.attempts >= settings.maxAttempts) {
        throw new Error('poll(): max attempts reached');
    }

    // Do the work, and recurse on error
    try {
        return await work();
    }
    catch (e) {
        await delay(settings.delay);
        settings.attempts += 1; // Mutate/pass `settings`; the original `options` is not guaranteed to have an `attempts` property.
        return await poll(work, settings, token);
    }
}
```

Call as follows:

```
// token
const token = {}; // or {'stop':false} if you like

// Time based timer:
setTimeout(() => {
    token.stop = true; // raise the 'stop' flag
}, 60000); // or whatever

let pollPromise = poll(doSomethingAsync, {'delay':1000, 'maxAttempts':100}, token)
.then((res) => console.log(res))
.catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

Note that on setting the stop signal:

1. a successful reponse from in-flight work will still come through.
2. further recursion will be prevented but no attempt is made to abort the in-flight work.

With a little more thought these behaviours could be changed depending on exactly what is required.